# internal and external network with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose I have 2 docker containers: (A) `shinyapptest` is a front end that needs to communicate with (B) `testapi` and be accessible to the outside world.

To do this I created a network `backend` by running the following command:

```sh
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 backend
```

Then `shinyapptest` makes its API calls to `"http://192.168.0.1:3098`.

To get everything up and running I wrote the following `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    shinyapptest:
      container_name: testshiny
      image: testshiny
      restart: unless-stopped
      networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
      ports:
          - 80:3838
    testapi:
      container_name: testapi
      image: testapi
      restart: unless-stopped
      networks:
            - backend
      ports:
          - 3098:3098
networks:
  backend:
    external:
      name: backend
  frontend:
    external:
      name: frontend
```

Is this right? Basically, I want (A) to have access to (B) and the outside world to have access to (A) but not (B). If this is right, how should I create the `frontend` network? Right now if I try to run `docker-compose up` I get this error because the network does not exist:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: Network frontend declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create frontend` and try again.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you don't even need the `frontend` network. If you attach the `backend` network to both containers they should be able to communicate with each other. Just like 2 computers on the same network.

If you don't want a container to be accessible from outside, simply don't map the respective port back into your host system. That will keep them isolated.

Currently your api has port `3098` exposed. If you remove that, but have the network attached to both containers you would be able to call port `3098` internally from your `frontend` container, but not from outside.

You may even use the assigned container name for **internal** communication, like so:

```
http://testapi:3098/...
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @TvG. I think i'm almost there but the internal communication is not working. I'm pointing [my app to http://testapi:3098/](https://github.com/ignacio82/testShinyPlumber/blob/7e291ff286e7048a51b444a93c780ce443480484/inst/app/server.R#L6) but I get an error that says "testapi’s server IP address could not be found." Do you know what could I be doing wrong? In case it helps, I uploaded all [my code to github](https://github.com/ignacio82/testShinyPlumber)

Comment: Your `frontend` contains an `iframe` which tries to fetch data from `testapi`. That does not work since all browser code was deliverd to the client and therefore runs on their network. You need to have some sort of `service` that delivers the `frontend`, as well as keeping connection to your `testapi`. This service then needs to be exposed to the "outside", since everyone would connect to it - thru their browsers. In that case you could also just expose your `backend` directly, which you don't want. But there is no other way, since `frontend` and `testapi` run on different networks anyways.